# change model admin form default value

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have typical model inheritance in my project:

```
class A(models.Model):
    boolean_field = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class B(A):
    some_other_field = models.CharField()
```

I want to override default value of `boolean_field` in class `B`, how can I do it?

I think that could be tricky thing to do on a database layer, so maybe at least I can simply override that default value in Django admin (I mean in `ModelAdmin` form for class `B`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suggest, I think the easiest approach is to change the model form used for the `B` model in the django admin.

To change the initial value of the form field, you can either redefine the field, or override the `__init__` method.

```
class BForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # either redefine the boolean field
    boolean_field = models.BooleanField(initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = B

    # or override the __init__ method and set initial=False
    # this is a bit more complicated but less repetitive
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['boolean_field'].initial = False
```

Using your custom model form in the django admin is easy!

```
class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BForm

admin.site.register(B, BAdmin)
```

Comment: The `__init__` way is better, so the field in the model can be changed without having to manually reflect those changes in the modelform, since only one parameter is changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A(models.Model):
    boolean_field = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self. boolean_field 


class B():
    some_other_field = models.CharField()
    default_fiel_from_bool = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33648806/606725), the easiest way I've found is to override the function `get_changeform_initial_data`.

Here's how I applied it to my project.

In this example, I have a ORM class called `Step` and an Admin class called `StepAdmin`.  The function `get_latest_step_order` gets the `step_order` from the latest object in the table.

By overriding the `get_changeform_initial_data` function in the admin class I'm able to set the step order for each new object that's created in the admin screen.

```
class Step(models.Model):
    step_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    step_status = models.ForeignKey(StepStatus, null=True)
    step_order = models.IntegerField()


def get_latest_step_order():
    return Step.objects.latest('step_order').step_order+1

class StepAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ["step_name","step_status","step_order"]

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {
            'step_order': get_latest_step_order()
        }
```

Comment: Only update I'd make to this is to also call the super function first to get the main default dictionary for other values too. Something like:

`defaults = super().get_changeform_initial_data(request)`
`defaults['step_order'] = get_latest_step_order()`